Show $T_p(M) = \{v: \limsup_{r\to 0}r^{-2}d(p+rv,M)<\infty\}$.
Let $M$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb R^N$, that is, a $C^3$ submanifold of dimension $N-1$ without boundary. Given $p\in M$, the tangent space $T_p(M)$ is the collection of $v\in \mathbb R^N$ for which there is a $C^2$ curve $\gamma : I\to M$ with $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\dot \gamma(0) = v$. I am trying to do an exercise which asks me to show that
$$T_p(M) = \underbrace{\left\{v\in \mathbb R^N: \limsup_{r\to 0}\frac{d(p+rv,M)}{r^2}<\infty\right\}}_E\,,$$
where $d$ is the usual distance between a set and a point. One direction is easy. Indeed, given $v\in T_p(M)$, fix a $C^2$ curve $\gamma$ and the inclusion $T_p(M)\subset E$ immediately follows by  Taylor's Theorem. I am having trouble showing the reverse conclusion, as I can't see how to construct a curve that works.

Can you show that if $v\notin T_pM$, then that distance is not $o(r)$?

You can project each point on $M$ near $p$ orthogonally onto $T_pM$. This is a diffeomorphism. Its inverse maps a curve in $T_pM$ to one in $M$.

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$It suffices to prove this if $p$ is the origin and the tangent plane at $0$ is $$H= { x^N = 0 }. $$ Then in a neighborhood $O\subset H$ of $0$, there exists a function $f: O \rightarrow \R$ whose graph is $M\cap (O\times\R)$. Observe that $f(0) = 0$ and $\nabla f(0) = 0$. From here, the rest is straightforward.

Hi @Deane Thanks for the suggestion. To clarify,  are we identifying $H$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^{N-1}$?

Yes, that’s rifgt

Choose a point $p\in M$ and consider some unit vector $v\in N_pM$ (normal vector of $M$ at $p$). Then for sufficiently small $r$
$$
d(p+rv,M)=|r|
$$
and hence
$$
{d(p+rv,M)\over r^2}=\frac{|r|}{r^2}=\frac{1}{|r|}\overset{r\to 0}{\longrightarrow}\infty.
$$
This might merit a more careful argument but the intuition is pretty clear: Locally around $p$ the manifold $M$ looks like a hyperplane and the distance of a point to the hyperplane is just the length of the normal vector of the plane connecting the plane with said point.
Therefore $v$ (or any non-zero multiple of $v$) is not contained in $E$. If you show that $E$ is indeed a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^N$, then we have shown that $\dim(E)\leq N-1$. Since $T_pM\subseteq E$ and $\dim(T_pM)=N-1$, we also have $\dim(E)=N-1$. Hence the two subspaces have to be equal.

Added in response to comments: I was just appealing to intuition. Making this heuristic argument precise might not be the most "efficient" way to prove the claim. Nevertheless let my try to make it more precise:
We may assume that $p=0\in \mathbb R^N$ and that the tangent hyperplane of $M$ at $p$ is just the subspace $\mathbb R^{N-1}\times\lbrace 0\rbrace$. Further we can find a $C^3$-function $f\colon\mathbb R^{N-1}\to \mathbb R$ and an open neighborhood $U\subseteq \mathbb R^N$ of $p$ such that $U\cap M$ is part of the graph of $f$. Let $r_0>0$ be such that $\overline{B_{r_0}(p)}\subseteq U$.
For a given $r\leq r_0$ it's clear that $d(p+rv,M)\leq |r|$ so that any point on $M$ minimizing the distance has to lie within $\overline{B_r(p)}\subseteq \overline{B_{r_0}(p)}$.
The above heuristic argument is only valid "infinitessimally", i.e. we actually have
$$
d(p+rv,T_pM)=|r|.
$$
Taylor's theorem tells us that $f(x)=O(\lVert x\rVert^2)$ for $x\to 0$, i.e. there exists a $\delta_0>0$ with $\delta_0\leq r_0$ and a constant $c>0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq c\lVert x\rVert^2$ for $\lVert x\rVert \leq \delta_0$.
For each point $(x,f(x))\in M\cap \overline{B_{r}(p)}$ we have
$$
\lVert x\Vert\leq \lVert (x,f(x))\rVert \leq r,
$$
so that for $r\leq \delta_0$ points $q\in M\cap \overline{B_{r}(p)}$ satisfy
$$
d(q,T_pM)\leq c\,r^2
$$
and therefore
$$
d(p+rv,q)\geq d(p+rv,T_pM)-d(q,T_pM)\geq |r|-cr^2.
$$
Finally we can conclude that for sufficiently small $r$ we have
$$
{d(p+rv,M)\over r^2}\geq \frac{1}{|r|}-c\overset{r\to 0}{\longrightarrow} \infty.
$$

Could you give some hint on how to show the first assertion?

@Andrew I have reconsidered some aspects of my revised answer and believe that I have succeeded in making the heuristic argument more precise.

Helpful, thanks!
